# How to alert if someone goes on a website other than the IP address listed?

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

I have a snort rule

```
alert tcp any -> !142.250.200.14 any (msg:"Bad Website"; sid:1000002; rev:1;)
```

The problem is it logs all websites, including the one listed as 142.250.200.14 as 'bad website'.

I want all websites to be alerted except 142.250.200.14, is there an easy fix to the rule?

I suspect it has something to do with the '!', but I'm not sure.

PS. I'm a newbie.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on a site where it is on-topic, such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: You have that on the destination side.  So, that will log any access from anywhere that isn't going to 142.250.200.14.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want to allow INCOMING access from that IP.

Comment: And technically, you should use "any any" so you have an IP and port on both sides.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, so I want to alert when someone on the network or on the host pc (whichever is easier) if someone diverts from 142.250.200.14. So if someone goes onto a different 'website', it will display an alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list and iterate through that. You can reverse the effect or avoid it this way.